# How to prevent adding elements to a DOM node?

Tags: javascript

I have a pretty disgusting issue. "Disgusting" because I do not have full control of the whole webpage and therefore have to hack my way to success.

### Situation

I have my own script, which is loaded into the webpage, and a `div` container, that displays the page´s navigation. I want to add a link to that container and that container should only contain that single link.

### Problem

There is a third party script, which also adds links to that container. It does that inside a AJAX callback function

### What I have tried

**1. Deleting all links but mine after document is completely loaded**

This is not possible because third party script loads content via AJAX callback, so when page is fully loaded the unwanted links have not been rendered yet.

**2. Renaming `div` container**

After adding my link to the container I stripped the container completely naked, deleting class names, IDs etc. But the third party script still finds that container.

**3. Attaching `DOMNodeInserted` event to the container**

Works great in anything that I call a browser. But fails in IE. And the IE is the main browser the user of that page use.

**What else can I try?**

Comment: So the main idea is to break the other script, or to coexist ? :)

Comment: Don't you think your third party concurrent will ask the same thing once you're done?

Comment: @hamilton.lima: Still coexist, but keeping that container just for me.

Comment: Is the function adding the unwanted stuff in the `window` namespace?

Comment: `After adding my link to the container I stripped the container completely naked, deleting class names, IDs etc. But the third party script still finds that container.` Probably script finds dom object by tag name, so change it to another tag.

Comment: @PLB: Unfortunately that will mess with the CSS

Comment: @Cerbrus: Not exactly. But I can access it from everywhere. It lies withing third party´s own namespace, which is of course part of the `window` namespace.

Comment: Then that means you can override the function.

Comment: Delete the entire div. If the third-party script is looking for tag names you can do what @PLB says and use a different tag

Comment: @Cerbrus: I already tried deleting the namespace which executes the AJAX function (two different namespaces) and that did not work. But I will try override the executing function itself.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Overriding will not work. I do not know how all the modules and extensions are connected to each other. It is a huge project. Simply overriding does not do it. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the third party script uses jQuery then you can try [ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/).

Comment: It is actually using jQuery. +1 for that idea. I will give it a try.

Comment: That actually did the trick. Even though it is very annoying to make a round trip to the server just to delete its response.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to DOMSubtreeModified event, and restore original div state.

```
var originalChildren = $('#content').children();

var setOriginal = function(e) {
    $('#content').off('DOMSubtreeModified');
    $('#content').empty().append(originalChildren);
    $('#content').on('DOMSubtreeModified', setOriginal);
};

$('#content').on('DOMSubtreeModified', setOriginal);
```

[Test it](http://jsfiddle.net/rQtEq/).

Answer (score 0):

You could override/wrap the DOM methods the other script is using to add elements, such as appendChild(). Something like this (psuedocode)

```
var originalAppend = document.appendChild;
document.appendChild = function () {
    if condition {
        originalAppend.apply(document, arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's going to break pretty much everything when you're doing that on native functions, though.

Comment: The third party script is a huge player. I have not looked into the whole code, but I think they are smart enough to preserve all native functions.

Comment: Third party scripts might rely on native functions functioning like they should. If there is one specific function that inserts the unwanted elements, and does only that, you can probably safely edit it. Just don't mess with native functionalities.